# Accessing and changing the renderer component properties in <a-scene>

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

Below is a code snippet in A-Frame that I am using. I wish to access and manipulate the maxCanvasWidth and maxCanvasHeight properties of the renderer component using conditional statements in Javascript. I can't figure out how to do it.

```
<a-scene renderer ="antialias: true;

                   colorManagement: true;`

                   sortObjects: true;

                   physicallyCorrectLights: true;

                   maxCanvasWidth: 1920;

                   maxCanvasHeight: 1920;"></a-scene>

Example pseudo code of what I wish to implement:
<script>
var update = document.queryselector('a-scene');
if(fps < 60){
update.maxCanvasWidth = 800;
update.maxCanvasHeight = 800; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was able to figure it out:

```
sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
sceneEl.maxCanvasSize = {height: , width: };
```

Answer (score 1):

`renderer` is an attribute of the scene element, so you would use `setAttribute`. Specifically, refer to the documentation on [updating multi-property component data.](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#updating-multi-property-component-data)

e.g.

```js
const scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
scene.setAttribute('renderer', 'maxCanvasWidth', 800);
```